# How can I sort a list numerically from a specific part of a string

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this list of links that need to be sorted when they are generated on my page.

The links appear like this

`"https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%208975%###"
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%207600%###"`

I then map through them when they are generated onto my page, and create a name based on whats at the end of the link (removing all the junk characters).

Is it possible, without altering the url, to sort them numerically based on the what's at the end of the url. That way when I map through them, they are already ordered.

**Like this:**

`NF%207600%###`

`NF%208975%###`

I've looked through some similar SO questions, but can't seem to find anything relative enough.

Comment: Why isn't a natural sort working for you?

Comment: Do the `###` indicate that they are placeholders for any arbitrary string?

Comment: @PeterMader yes, can't include the whole link because it contains sensitive info. I left the portion that I want to sort by open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *regex* to extract the number and then compare by it:

```js
var urls = ["https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%208975%###", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%207600%###"]

function extract_number(url) {
    return Number(url.replace(/.*%(\d+)%.*/, "$1"))
}

urls.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(extract_number(a) < extract_number(b)) {
        return -1;
    } 
    if(extract_number(a) > extract_number(b)) {
        return 1;
    } 
    return 0;
})

console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Hah! Knew someone was gonna post something like this... for a lot of URLs, it's better to precalculate all the `extract_number()`s before the `sort()`, so then you only have to do it once per URL rather than log(N) per URL.

Comment: Not all that familiar with regex, but the numbers could come after any string characters. `RF` for example is another example of many more. How could I modify this solution for that?

Comment: What is the pattern that identifies the number? Can the two `%`s uniquely identify the number?

Comment: The other thing is, you can simply `return extract_number(a) - extract_number(b)`

Comment: @Psidom sometimes it can look like this `10.250%20test%20doc`

Comment: So you want to sort based on `20`(before the word *test*)?

Comment: @Psidom I think he's saying to avoid URL-encoded characters. `%20` is `escape(" ")`. The `RegExp` you had with just `%(\d+)%` should work fine, I think.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts OK. That makes sense. But still not sure if `%20` is the character that identifies the number to sort by.

Comment: Since the format is unclear, I think the "correct" regex is of little concern compared to showing how to sort an array based on a processed result of each entry.

Comment: @Psidom sorry for the confusion. `%20` does not necessarily mark the beginning of the string to sort by. There's a lot of links to look at, but it looks like the number will either come before or after the first `%20`. Like such `10.250%20test%20doc` or `NF%208975%###`

Comment: Then my suggestion would be make a list of the urls that you can have; Identify the pattern and figure out the regex you need to extract the number. If you can post in comments, maybe I could help. Or you can post a different question about *regex*.

Comment: @psidom thanks for the help. There's thousands of urls to look at, so it might take some time... accepting your answer for now as it has gotten me the closest to my needed solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can `.map().sort().map()`. It may seem bulky, but if you have a lot of URLs, this is more performant since you don't have to perform a number-parsing regex-replace every time you compare a URL to another one. For example, compare the amount of calls when sorting just 5 URLs:

```js
var array = [
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%208975%###',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%209213%###',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%205346%###',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%201764%###',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/###/NF%207600%###'
];

function getId(url) {
  return Number(url.replace(/^.*%(\d+)%.*$/, '$1'));
}

function count(func) {
  function wrapper() {
    wrapper.count++;
    return func.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  
  wrapper.count = 0;
  
  return wrapper;
}

var countGetId = count(getId);

var sorted = array
  .map(url => ({ url, number: countGetId(url) }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
  .map(obj => obj.url);

console.log('.map().sort().map()')
console.log(sorted);
console.log('getId called ' + countGetId.count + ' times');

var countGetId = count(getId);

var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => countGetId(a) - countGetId(b))

console.log('.sort()')
console.log(sorted);
console.log('getId called ' + countGetId.count + ' times');
```

So, just do this:

```
function getId(url) {
  return Number(url.replace(/^.*%(\d+)%.*$/, '$1'));
}

var sorted = array
  .map(url => ({ url, number: getId(url) }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
  .map(obj => obj.url);

console.log(sorted);
```